# Mokka pot coffee homogeneity

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I've noticed some people pouring coffee from a mokka pot alternates between two cups instead of directly filling one after the other. The reason argued is related to the beverage homogeneity, as the initial vapor will go through totally fresh coffee, in opposition to the very last drops. Neglecting the possible solid residuum, I intuitively see no reason supporting this, as for the few minutes while the coffee is raising to the upper recipient, it will fall along the external walls of the central chimney, even inducing a ring-vortex-like circulation around it, depending on the geometry of the chimney aperture.

I've thought a simple transparent model of the pot to see this, but I would like to ask for possible Comsol(/alternative software) model results that may already exist and I don't manage to find, as I have no active licenses. I would also thank further arguments supporting what may actually happen.

Answer (score 0):

I think the explanation about the stages of the percolation process is incorrect, for the reasons that the OP describes. What seems more plausible is that more dense coffee layers (regardless of when they originate) descend while the pot is boiling, so the coffee at the top is more diluted (another possibility is that the coffee at the top is less polluted with small cofee partciles, i.e., the sediment). For other beverages this is usually fixed by shaking the bottle/container, but this method is impractical with a mokka pot.

Comment: The point for me is if the final result, after a minute to leave solid particles deposit, is homogeneous in colour/taste/... (Serving a few mm in a sequence of identical glasses doesn't show apreciable colour difference). I assume inertia of the stream falling around the chimney and convection to be fast enough to dismantle the foundations of the mentioned technique.

Comment: If we assume the sediment as the problem, then the person getting the last cup is risking to have all the sediment or less coffee (in tea drinking this is usually avoided by using a filter). Then, my experience with mokka is that in a cup it remains "clouded" for a long time, although rather homogeneous. I however never share my coffee with anyone, especially stragers ;)

Comment: Solid particles were not in the argument, only fluid and long lasting suspended particles. Sediment is kept by decantation quite effectively if leaving a bit of water is not a problem. I assume this suspended cloud should be... rather homogeneous.

Comment: What I mean is that the decantation prevents one from distributing the coffee in equal quantities. In a real expresso machine one is certainly justified in filling the two cups simultaneously, rather than one by one (when using the same doze of coffee) - there the difference can be quite noticeable.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding something. We can assume the quantities can be slightly different, or the half volume estimation is good enough when serving. The two modes are not simultaneous vs one after the other, but "a bit for A, a bit for B, a bit for A, a bit for B..." recursively until last drops with sediment are considered to be the next ones to fall, vs ~1/2 the clean volume for A and then the remaining ~1/2 for B.

Comment: I am just trying to find a justification for using the technique described in the OP: if many people do this, there might be actually a good reason or empirical evidence, even if their explanation is incorrect.